# need to install open ipmi on a remote HP DL20 server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ipmi, ilo, ipmitool

I have an ubuntu(18.04.2 LTS) image running on a HP DL20, This server has a dedicated iLO, but i fear some settings are wrong as i cant reach the iLO. I would like to install open ipmi on the server to check gateway/subnet thats set in the bios. However my server does not have external internet access as in i cant run 'apt-get install -y openipmi". I could however scp a file from my SFTP server to the machine and install locally. However I cant figure out how to get the local package. Yesterday i found a tar.gz for open ipmi and de-compressed it, yet when i ran the instructions in the read me, i would get a error in the ./config script. and then when i would do "make" it would stop. I'm assuming I need some kind of make package installed as well? is there a simpler way to install open ipmi? im all out of ideas here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a different machine to download the package and its dependencies.
Something along the lines of what is described in https://www.ostechnix.com/download-packages-dependencies-locally-ubuntu/ might help.

However, the same distribution needs to be used.

Comment: this worked perfectly! thanks!!